# Sublime Text console not showing lines with accents

Tags: unicode, utf-8, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 2 and 3, the console output doesn't show the lines with accents on it:

[image: Example]

I'm using `Tools > Build` in vanilla Sublime in Windows with automatic Build System to execute it.

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3, but the problem is the same with Python 2 however

Comment: @Basj the example in this question seems to work fine out of the box in the latest Sublime with the script presented and Python 3; are you saying that this is still an issue for you as presented here?

Comment: @OdatNurd I still use (the latest version of) Python 2.7 for some projects.

Comment: @Basj Hmm.. it seems to work for me there as well (or with 2.7.14 anyway); are you on Sublime 3.1? Perhaps you have a modified version of the `Default/exec.py` plugin that I helped you with previously?

Comment: @jcrs It seems fixed with the last Sublime Text version (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the encoding of standard system output in your document to `UTF-8`:

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter( "utf-8" )( sys.stdout.detach() )

print( "1" )
print( "áéíóúý âêîôû äëïöü àèìòù ãñõ" )
print( "2" )
```

---

To automatically apply `UTF-8` encoded output to all documents, implement the previous method as an inline `command` within your `Python.sublime-build` file.

After the encoding has been set, your document is loaded via `exec` within the inline `command`.

```
{
    "cmd": [ "python", "-u", "-c", "import sys; import codecs; sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter( 'utf-8' )( sys.stdout.detach() ); exec( compile( open( r'$file', 'rb' ).read(), r'$file', 'exec'), globals(), locals() )" ],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```

**Tip:** Use [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to create a [**user copy**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37127271/4955183) of `Python.sublime-build`

---

Tested with `Sublime Text 3` ( *Stable Channel, Build 3103* ) and `Python` 3.4.3

---

#### Sources:

[**How to set sys.stdout encoding in Python 3?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4374457/4955183)

[**Alternative to execfile in Python 3?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357418/4955183)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but since printing accents works on other consoles, I'm wondering if there is a fix at Sublime side, to avoid adding this code to every single project.

Comment: @jcrs: I just updated the answer with a build method.

Comment: It's a bit hackish to have to add this each time we do a new Python script involving utf8 characters. Strangely, this problem is not present in SublimeText 2.

Comment: @Basj Definitely a hack, but it does not have to be added for each Python script. If you revisit the 2nd section of the answer (after "To automatically apply.."), you'll see that the hack boilerplate is incorporated into a build system. Meaning that all scripts run with that build system will work with proper UTF-8 encoded output.

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner solution is to specify the encoding as a part of the build settings

```
{   
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env": {
        "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf_8"
    },
}
```

This works in most cases. But in certain cases you may need to remove the `-u` which is basically to stop unbuffered output, as it may cause issues

[image: Encoding]

See below thread for discussion on a similar issue

[Python 2.7 build on Sublime Text 3 doesn't print the '\uFFFD' character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856584/python-2-7-build-on-sublime-text-3-doesnt-print-the-ufffd-character/47305036#47305036)

Answer (score 0):

It seems fixed with Sublime Text 3.2.2 build 3211: when I open `test.py` containing:

```
print("1")
print("á")
print("2")
```

then when building with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (using Python 3.6), then it works normally, out-of-the-box.

---

Remark: the default `Python.sublime-build` is indeed now:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```