# How to show "±" in python?

Tags: python, ascii, extended-ascii

Just a sample question. Is it possible to show the symbol `±` in Python?
I just tried to use the Extended ASCII Codes `char(241)`, but it didn't work.

The simple code:

```
b = chr(241)    #The Extended ASCII Codes for 241 is this symbol "±".
print(b)
```

The result showed `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Can someone help? Thanks

**I just want to test if I could show the Extended ASCII Codes in Python. There is no complicated code.**

Here is the code and result: [image]

Comment: @abccd Got it. I just thought, there are actually only one assignment and one print statement in the code. It's not very necessary to write the code. Th e screenshot is more clear. So could you please tell me how to show this symbol correctly? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `print('±')`?

Comment: @DYZ It cannot be showed. I said the result in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652904/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character)

Comment: Try `b = '\x00\xB1'` (python 3)

Comment: @cdarke I tried. Same result. It said that "'ascii' code can't encode character '\xb1' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)".

Comment: range(128) is basic 7-bit ASCII, not extended.  Which version of python are you using, and are you running it on a console which supports extended ASCII or Unicode?  For example, Windows cmd.exe has poor support for these characters (although I have not tried that one).

Comment: @cdarke I use 3.6.1. And I run the code in Sublime Text.

Comment: I'm also running 3.6.1 and it works fine for me.  Check the Sublime documentation for console settings, or run your program from a command-line which supports the correct character set.

Comment: @cdarke Got it. It works with the command-line.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121558/sublime-text-console-not-showing-lines-with-accents

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments, any of the following alternatives can be applied

```
print('±') # Provided your terminal supports Unicode
print('\xB1') # For all cases.
```

Comment: `print('\xB1') # For all cases`