# Sublime Text 3 not printing correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3

I have the following code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    player_information = get_information()
    print "Goalkeepers top 10:"
    goalkeepers = get_position(player_information, "Goalkeeper")
    for player, points in get_top_players(goalkeepers, 10, 5):
        print goalkeepers[player]["name"], points

    print "\nDefenders top 10:"
    defenders = get_position(player_information, "Defender")
    for player, points in get_top_players(defenders, 10, 5):
        print defenders[player]["name"], points

    print "\nMidfielders top 10:"
    midfielders = get_position(player_information, "Midfielder")
    for player, points in get_top_players(midfielders, 10, 5):
        print midfielders[player]["name"], points

    print "\nForwards top 10:"
    forwards = get_position(player_information, "Forward")
    for player, points in get_top_players(forwards, 10, 5):
        print forwards[player]["name"], points
```

Output when using `Ctrl + B` on Sublime Text 3 (I have already selected `Python` after clicking `Ctrl + Shift + B`).

```
Goalkeepers top 10:
de Gea 33
Ryan 23
Schmeichel 23
Lössl 22
Ederson 22
Pope 22
Forster 21
Mignolet 21
Hart 20
Courtois 19

Defenders top 10:
Monreal 32
Jones 32
Azpilicueta 30
Trippier 29
Kolasinac 28
Otamendi 27
Fuchs 24
Bellerín 23
Ward 23
Valencia 23

Midfielders top 10:
Ramsey 30
Coutinho 28
Richarlison 28
Mahrez 27
Fernandinho 27
Eriksen 27
David Silva 26

Forwards top 10:
Kane 44
Abraham 30
Diouf 28
Lacazette 25
Lukaku 25
Morata 24
Murray 22
Rashford 21
Jesus 20
Niasse 20
```

For some reason the Midfielder bit isn't printing correctly (only printing 7 out of 10 players). However, when running from the file from a terminal it prints completely fine, as seen below:

```
Goalkeepers top 10:
de Gea 33
Ryan 23
Schmeichel 23
Lössl 22
Ederson 22
Pope 22
Forster 21
Mignolet 21
Hart 20
Courtois 19

Defenders top 10:
Monreal 32
Jones 32
Azpilicueta 30
Trippier 29
Kolasinac 28
Otamendi 27
Fuchs 24
Bellerín 23
Ward 23
Valencia 23

Midfielders top 10:
Sané 53
Sterling 38
De Bruyne 31
Ramsey 30
Coutinho 28
Richarlison 28
Mahrez 27
Fernandinho 27
Eriksen 27
David Silva 26

Forwards top 10:
Kane 44
Abraham 30
Diouf 28
Lacazette 25
Lukaku 25
Morata 24
Murray 22
Rashford 21
Jesus 20
Niasse 20
```

Just printing the points does result in the Sublime Text 3 output being the same, so I thought maybe it had something to do with the encoding, but that didn't change a thing.

Comment: Try to printout just `Sané` in Sublime and also rerun your program with `print repr(midfielders[player]["name"])`. What is the output?

Comment: @MaximTitarenko If I just print out `Sané` it works fine. Adding `repr` gives this for example: `u'San\xe9' 53` and prints out all 10 midfielders correctly.

Comment: `print u'San\xe9'` also works fine?

Comment: @MaximTitarenko No, for some reason that causes some other things to not be printed (like "Midfielders top 10:" doesn't get printed if I print that on the line before that).

Comment: Try to see what your stdoud encoding is: 1) `import sys` 2) `print sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: @MaximTitarenko It's `utf-8`.

Comment: Hmm, then I can't help, sorry. Btw, I have a similar problem with Sublime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856584/python-2-7-build-on-sublime-text-3-doesnt-print-the-ufffd-character

Comment: Maybe you can try `print u'San\xe9'.encode('utf-8')` or `print u'San\xe9'.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')`. If it works in the 2nd case it would be `San` in the output

Comment: It looks like the Sublime's bug. I have everything the same you described. Here is the crutch which should solve your problem: `print midfielders[player]["name"] + ' ', points` <-- add extra space to midfielders string